# The integer values of $\sum_{d|n}\frac{\sigma(n/d)^d}{d}$.

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

I was looking for integer values of the $$\sum_{d|n}\frac{\sigma(n/d)^d}{d}$$
where the $\sigma(n)$ is a divisors sum of $n$.

And amazingly has found that the only integer values for $n<1500000$ are:
$$1, 39, 793$$

So I assume that these are the only integer numbers of this kind.

Any ideas how to prove or disprove this?

The according OEIS sequence is:
https://oeis.org/A268983

EDITED:
With @RobertIsrael help in question [The solution of congruences system.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274223/the-solution-of-congruences-system) and according to @user1952009 comment I have found the next item in this sequence:
$$2408321608150261253061174553 = 22419767768701 * 107419560853453$$

Comment: $39 = 13 \times 3,793 = 13\times 61{}{}{}$

Comment: You might want to edit your OEIS entry, since the conjecture is now disproven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(n) =\sum_{d | n} \frac{\sigma(n/d)^d}{d}$$
If $p,q$ are two different primes then
$$f(pq) =\sigma(pq) + \frac{p(p+1)^q + q (q+1)^p + 1}{pq}$$
For $f(pq) \in \mathbb{Z}$
we need $p(p+1)^q + q (q+1)^p + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and $q$

$$\implies \qquad q (q+1)\equiv -1 \bmod p, \qquad p (p+1)\equiv -1 \bmod q$$
(by the Fermat little theorem)

Letting $g(n) = \sum_{d | n} \frac{\sigma(n/d)}{d}$ which is multiplicative, then  $f(pq) \in \mathbb{Z}$  iff $$\sigma(pq)+\frac{p(p+1) + q (q+1) + 1}{pq}=g(pq)=g(p)g(q)= (p+1+\frac{1}{p})(q+1+\frac{1}{q}) \quad \in \mathbb{Z}$$

---

With this matlab program I didn't find more solutions :

```
for a = [1:3200]
    A = a*(a+1)+1; fac = factor(A);
    for j = 1:length(fac)
        p = fac(j);
        if p > a
            P = p*(p+1)+1; fac2 = factor(P);
            for j2 = 1:length(fac2)
                q = fac2(j2);
                if mod(q,p) == a    fprintf('%d %d \n', p,q);   end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This is really interesting idea to test the pairs: $$\qquad q (q+1)\equiv -1 \bmod p, \qquad p (p+1)\equiv -1 \bmod q$$ I have tested this for primes up to $100000$. And again no other solutions.

Comment: The mathematica program is: DeleteDuplicates[
 Flatten[Table[
   Table[If[
     Mod[p*(p + 1) + 1 , q] == 0 && Mod[q*(q + 1) + 1 , p] == 0 , p*q,
      Nothing], {p, Prime[Range[q, PrimePi[1000000]]]}], {q, 
    Prime[Range[PrimePi[1000000]]]}]]]