# The solution of congruences system.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

From the answer of user1952009: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2273035.

Looking for the general solution of system for prime $p$ and $q$: $$q^2+q+1\equiv 0 \bmod p\\ p^2+p+1\equiv 0 \bmod q$$
EDITED: The following solution found:
$$p=3,q=13\\p=13,q=61\\p=22419767768701,q=107419560853453$$

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ prime numbers or any natural numbers?

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A101368](https://oeis.org/A101368) and links there.

Comment: Yes p and q are primes.

Comment: Many thants to @RobertIsrael I have found the other solution with primes: p*q=2408321608150261253061174553